# Jordan normal form of $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 4 & 1 & 1 \\ -2 & 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 & 4 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

I want to find the Jordan normal form of $A=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 & 1 \\ -2 & 1 & -2 \\ 1 & 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$, but somewhere I think that I make a mistake (I am quite new to the computation of the Jordan normal form).
I could find that $\lambda=3$ is $A$'s only eigenvalue and its algebraic multiplicity is $3$.
Afterwards, I solved the system $(A-3I_3)X=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and I got that $x=\begin{pmatrix} -a-b \\ a \\ b \end{pmatrix}$ for some parametres $a, b\in \mathbb{C}$.
I picked the eigenvectors $X_1=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $X_2=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and then I got stuck. I tried solving both the equations $(A-3I_3)X'=X_1$ and $(A-3I_3)X''=X_2$, but these have no solutions, so I can't find any generalised eigenvectors. What should I do?

Comment: What do you need a generalized eigenvector for? You already know the geometric multiplicity of the unique eigenvalue is 2, so....or equivalently: you already know what the dimension of the eigenspace of $\;\lambda=3\;$ is ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I would like to find the similarity matrix, I forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1):

After you get the Jordan form (as psidaga's answer did)
\begin{align*}
J = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align*}
in order to determine the similarity matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = J$, it is is equivalent to solve the system
\begin{align*}
& A\alpha_1 = 3\alpha_1, \tag{1} \\
& A\alpha_2 = \alpha_1 + 3\alpha_2, \tag{2} \\
& A\alpha_3 = 3\alpha_3,
\end{align*}
where $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$ are three columns of $P$. As you did, you can fix $\alpha_3$ to be $(-1, 0, 1)^T$. To determine $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$, note that $A - 3I_{(3)}$ is nilpotent with nilpotent index $2$, i.e., $(A - 3I_{(3)})^2 = 0$, hence any non-zero vector $\alpha_2$ that is not already an eigenvector and $\alpha_1 := (A - 3I_{(3)})\alpha_2$ would satisfy equations $(1)$ and $(2)$, since $(A - 3I_{(3)})\alpha_1 = (A - 3I_{(3)})^2\alpha_2 = 0$. For example, let $\alpha_2 = (1, 0, 0)^T$, then $\alpha_1 = (1, -2, 1)^T$. It can be easily verified that
\begin{align*}
P = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 \\
-2 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
is invertible and satisfies $A = PJP^{-1}$.

Of course, $P$ is not unique, depending on what $\alpha_2$ you are choosing.

Comment: Thank you, I think that I understand this! Where did I go wrong? I mean, shouldn't my method have yielded a vector?

Comment: Why are you trying to solve $(A - 3I)X' = X_1$?

Comment: I read an algorithm and it said that if I found that $X'$ it would be called a generalized eigenvector and I could use it for my matrix $P$

Comment: In my experience, your "algorithm" should be more likely going a reversed direction. That is, first determine an $x$ (like $\alpha_2$ in my answer), which is called the generator of the cyclic space, then get "generalized eigenvectors" by directly apply $(A - \lambda I), \ldots, (A - \lambda I)^{t - 1}$ on $x$ to get the basis for that cyclic space, where $t$ is the dimension of the cyclic space. Your way is rarely seen...

Comment: I see, but even this algorithm should give me a solution, right? I mean, it is technically correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "this algorithm"?

Comment: I mean the one that I tried to use i.e. trying to solve $(A-3I)X'=X_1 or (A-3I)X''=X_2$ in order to find the generalized eigenvector.

Comment: If you didn't get what you want by following it, then it might not be a "technically correct" algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two linearly independent eigenvectors, you know that there are two blocks for $\lambda=3$. That is already enough to tell you what the Jordan form looks like.

So it is not really necessary to look for generalized eigenvectors, if you *only* want Jordan form. But still, it might be useful to try this - especially since you've mentioned problems with this part in your question.

---

We want to have a solution for $(A-3I)X'=X$, where $X$ is an eigenvector. We do not know which eigenvector to chose for $X$, so let us try to do this with *arbitrary* eigenvector.

$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  1 & 1 & 1 &-a-b \\
 -2 &-2 &-2 & a \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & b
\end{array}\right)\sim
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  0 & 0 & 0 &-a-2b \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & a+2b \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & b
\end{array}\right)$

Already after these two steps we see, that this is only possible if $a+2b=0$. For example, if we choose $b=1$ and $a=-2$, then the above system is
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$
and one of the solutions is $(1,0,0)^T$. This is what we can choose for our generalized eigenvector.

---

Another thing worth noticing is that if we want to have $(A-3I)X'=X$ then $X$ needs to be in the column space of the matrix $(A-3I)$. So we have $X$ in the span of $(1,-2,1)^T$. For example, we can choose $X'=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $X=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

---

Once we found all eigenvectors and generalized eigenvectors, we can use them to get a matrix such that $A=PJP^{-1}$. So for
$$P=
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 &-1 \\
 -2 & 0 & 1 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
J=
\begin{pmatrix}
  3 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 3 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
we have $$A=PJP^{-1}.$$
One can check this by direct computation. Here is also a [link to WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B1%2C1%2C-1%5D%2C%5B-2%2C0%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C0%2C0%5D%5D*%5B%5B3%2C1%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C3%2C0%5D%2C%5B0%2C0%2C3%5D%5D*inverse%28%5B%5B1%2C1%2C-1%5D%2C%5B-2%2C0%2C1%5D%2C%5B1%2C0%2C0%5D%5D%29).